# First and second derivatives of the special functions

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the following special function.

$$f(x) = \sum _{i=1}^n \left\{\frac{(x - z_i)_+^2}{5+2 z_i +(x-z_i)_+^2}\right\} - \left\{(\frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{(x - z_i)_+^3}{3})\right\} $$

which `+` means If $z_i$ is bigger than x its equal $z_i - x$ and else it's equal zero.
Also $z_i$ is a  vector of value.
What is the first and second derivatives of this function with respect to x?

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace
$$
(x-z_i)_+^2 =  (x-z_i)^21_{(x-z_i)\geq0}
$$
where $1_{A}$ denotes the indecator function on the set $A$, and then use the fact that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(x-z_i)^21_{(x-z_i)\geq0} = 2(x-z_i)1_{(x-z_i)\geq0}.
$$